# I want a cross tab to find the response rate between two variables

Tags: r, dplyr, crosstab

Consider this data set named Survey which has 3 columns (Age_Group, Tenure and Campaign_Response):

```
ID<- seq(1:10)
Age_Group<-sample(c("Teen", "Adult", "Senior"), 10, replace = TRUE)
Tenure<-sample(c(1,2,3,4,5), 10, replace = TRUE)
Campaign_Response<-sample(c(T, F), 10, replace = TRUE)
Survey<-data.frame(Age_Group, Tenure, Campaign_Response)
```

I now want to create a cross tab of campaign response rate between age_group and tenure of customers. Could you please suggest the code for this. Thanks for all your help.

Comment: What is your expected output? Also could you reduce the number of observations to 10 or less so that it is easy to check?

Comment: Okay, I reduced the number of observations to 10. About the output, I want to analyse the trend for response rate for campaign between age_group and tenure.

Comment: Do you need `table(Survey$Age_Group, Survey$Tenure)` or probably `xtabs(Campaign_Response~Age_Group + Tenure, Survey)` ?

Comment: The above command explores the relationship between Age_Group and Tenure. Good!!. Now I want to go a step further and explore the relationship among 3 variables i.e. Age_Group , Tenure and Campaign_Response i.e. I want to find out the response rate between age_group and tenure. Is this possible

Comment: Yes, use of xtabs is what I needed. Now I got my answer. Great. Thanks a heap

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `xtabs` to get cross tabulation of campaign response rate with tenure and age.

```
xtabs(Campaign_Response ~ Age_Group+Tenure, data = Survey)
#            Tenure
# Age_Group 1 2 3 4 5
#     Adult 1 0 0 0 1
#    Senior 0 1 1 1 0
#      Teen 0 0 0 2 0
```

**Data:**

```
Survey <- structure(list(Age_Group = structure(c(3L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 3L, 2L, 2L, 1L, 1L, 3L), 
                                               .Label = c("Adult", "Senior", "Teen"),
                                               class = "factor"), 
                         Tenure = c(2, 1, 4, 2, 4, 3, 4, 5, 2, 4), 
                         Campaign_Response = c(FALSE, TRUE, FALSE, TRUE, TRUE, TRUE, TRUE, TRUE, FALSE, TRUE)),
                    .Names = c("Age_Group", "Tenure", "Campaign_Response"), 
                    row.names = c(NA, -10L), class = "data.frame")
```

Answer (score 0):

We can use `acast` from `reshape2`

```
library(reshape2)
acast(Survey, Age_Group~Tenure, sum)
#       1 2 3 4 5
#Adult  1 0 0 0 1
#Senior 0 1 1 1 0
#Teen   0 0 0 2 0
```